# IOS error Your app binary or metadata should not include placeholder text or images

Tags: ios, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I keep seeing this issue on IOS "app store" but on Android "Play store" it is has passed review no problem

The error:

- Your app binary or metadata should not include "lorem ipsum" text.
- App metadata should not include placeholder screenshots, such as "screenshot coming soon."

I am not sure why this error keeps occurring as I get all my images from my assets folder, and are referenced using firebase so I can add and replace Shopping items as needed.

I tried solving the issue by hardcoding the images but still the same result,

Comment: Did you checked the contents of firebase ? May be there are still test data in it.

Comment: Have you checked the screenshots you have added to AppStore connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As evident from your error itself. It seems that there is some test data left out in your project that is flagged by the app store. If you can globally search for "lorem ipsum" and any placeholder image that says "screenshot coming soon" and edit or remove those. I believe it should not give error any more